# accountbatch must implement the method: error in Batch class

Tags: apex, batch

I have tried to write a simple skeletal structure of the Batch apex class. I have included all the methods inside the batch apex.

However Im getting the below error message at the fist line of the code.

> Class accountbatch must implement the method: System.Iterable Database.Batchable.start(Database.BatchableContext)

Please find the batch class below.

```
global class accountbatch implements Database.Batchable<Account> {
    global database.QueryLocator Start (Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        String query = 'select id,Name from Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute (Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account> scope){

    }
    global void finish (Database.BatchableContext bc){}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
global class accountbatch implements Database.Batchable<Account>
```

with

```
global class accountbatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
```